# The elements is going up whenever I am using padding

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am having an issue with `padding` and `align-items: center`.

I am learning `grid` system. I am trying to make a header of a webpage with grid. But I am facing an issue. The elements is going up whenever I am using padding on the **Login button**.

Image after adding padding:
[image]

Image without adding padding:
[image]

My Code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
/* img {
    width: 100%;
} */
/* ========================= Header ========================= */
header {
    background: #19283f;
    width: 100%;
}
header a {
    color: white;
}
.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
header > .container > .container-1-1 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
}
header > .container > .container-1-1 > .container-1-1-2 {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}
header > .container > .container-1-1 > .container-1-1-2 > .menu {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto;
}
header > .container > .container-1-1 > .container-1-1-2 > .search {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}
header > .container > .container-1-1 > .container-1-1-2 > .search > .vertical {
    border-left: 2px solid white;
}
header > .container > .container-1-1 > .container-1-1-2 > .search > .icon {
}
header > .container > .container-1-1 > .container-1-1-2 > .search > button {
    background: #ff3150;
    border: transparent;
    border-radius: 0%;
    /* padding: 0.5rem 0; */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bondi</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="container-1-1">
                <div class="container-1-1-1">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="./images/logo.png" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="container-1-1-2">
                    <div class="menu">
                        <div><a href="#">Home</a></div>
                        <div><a href="#">Services</a></div>
                        <div><a href="#">Portfolio</a></div>
                        <div><a href="#">About</a></div>
                        <div><a href="#">Contact</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="search">
                        <div class="vertical"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-search" style="color: white;"></i>
                        <button><a href="#">Login</a></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-1-2"></div>
        </div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself.

I have added `align-items: center;` to the `header > .container > .container-1-1 > .container-1-1-2` class and the problem is solved.